# Export Data from AWS EC2 windows instance hosted in one account to S3 to another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to explore more on AWS S3 side and got one doubt. Is it possible to export data from EC2 windows instance hosted in one account to S3 bucket hosted in another AWS account? I know one way is using external modules like tntdrive where I can map S3 as mounted drive and export data. Looking for another good solution if S3 provides, so if someone knows this, please place your suggestions.

Comment: Are you just asking for general interest, or are you actually trying to move the data?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you would need in your EC2 instance is access to the AWS credentials of the other account, then you could copy your file from your EC2 instance to an S3 bucket for the second account.  You may also be able to do it if you grant the identity associated with the EC2 instance  rights to an S3 bucket owned by the second account - then you could just write to that bucket "yourself" ...

Comment: I created a IAM role on account where EC2 instance is hosted and delegated the permission to other account in S3 already. Also assigned the role that i have created to my existing EC2 instance by doing this i thought creating IAM user on EC2 instance account will suffice the request of calling the S3 bucket of another account but somehow its mapping is not working. Another way i guess creating user on another account and using its Access and Secret key will work in mapping.. Any possibility i can mount S3 as drive to my EC2 instance..

Comment: It is not recommended to mount Amazon S3 as a drive. Amazon S3 is an object store, not a file system. The easiest way to transfer data to/from Amazon S3 is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It has copy and sync commands. Either give it credentials from the account with the Amazon S3 bucket, or add permissions to the bucket that allow access from the other account.

Comment: Do understand the concept that S3 ideally not use for mounting. Only issue i dont want to create a script which will run to sync/copy the folders after every 15 mins. So that is why i am trying to get other solutions which might be easy enough to create and maintain.

Comment: I think what you mentioned you tried to set up should work - I would not work for alternatives, but rather try to work out what the problem with that is..